# What's the meaning of 'sheer' and 'times' in this context?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

“But then, when you’ve just come to the point when your reaction to the times is one of total and sheer acceptance, when your body has become somehow tuned into the insanity and you reach that point where it all makes sense"

Answer (score 1):

## [Sheer](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sheer)

> "nothing other than; unmitigated (used for emphasis)." -- OLD.

*Sheer acceptance* means total acceptance, and is actually more or less a tautology (redundant) giving the sentence already uses the word total.

But may have been used for poetic effect (to emphasize the totality of the acceptance).

## The times

Means the present day. It's the same idea used in the phrase:

[Sign of the times](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sign-of-the-times)

> Something that is typical of the (bad) way **things are now**. -- Cambridge.

(*My bold*) because this is what 'the times' in *sign of the times* refers to.